# How to import class from main.py to cogs/afile.py

Tags: class, import, discord, discord.py

I have some problem with importing a class from another file.
My file structure is like this:

```
bot/main.py
   /cogs/file1.py
         file2.py
         etc...
```

So I want to import a class from main.py to file.py.

I tried this way:

file1.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.\\')
import main
```

It's working, but after I import the class I can start the bot by running the file1.py file and not the main.py.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import from `..main` from within the cog files.